# covariance in numpy polyfit for two data points

Tags: python, numpy

I have two data points, x and y and the associated y error. I want to fit a straight line through the data points and calculate the error in the slope and intercept. When I try to use numpy ployfit with cov=True to get the covariance matrix in order to find the error it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (0,)
```

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,5])
y=np.array([1,5])
errors=np.array([0.2,0.4])
np.polyfit(x,y,1, w=errors, cov=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `np.polyfit(x,y,0, w=errors, cov=True)`?

Comment: @NickilMaveli that will plot a 0 degree ploynomial. This function is of x=y type (hence 1st degree polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. In order to calculate the covariance matrix, `polyfit` (which calls [`numpy.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)) needs the residuals. But the residuals for your fit are necessarily zero since your straight line will always go through both data points.

In fact, `lstsq` returns an empty array for `resid` whenever the rank of your coefficient matrix is less than or equal to `N`, the number of data points.

Perhaps you should ask what information you are hoping for from the "error in the slope and the intercept": what other values could they possibly take such that the ones "fitted" are the best in some sense?